# "Rules content empty" error in firestore using emulator, when changing firestore.rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Error:** On any change of firestore.rules, Firestore emulator output:

```
i  firestore: Change detected, updating rules...
**⚠  firestore.rules:0:0 - ERROR Rules content empty. Compilation aborted.**
✔  firestore: Rules updated.
```

**Platforms tried:** WSL as well as an Ubuntu VM under virtualbox

**Codelab:** https://google.dev/codelabs/firebase-emulator-test-rules

**Current firestore.rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /carts/{cartID} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ownerUID;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerUID;
    }
    match /carts/{cartID}/items/{itemID} {
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/carts/$(cartID)).data.ownerUID == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /items/{itemID} {
      allow read; // Users can read items
      // In a production app, don't allow unconditional write access!
      allow create; // For the codelab, client app uses this to add seed data.
    }
  }
}
```

**Project Configuration on Firebase console:** Only two modifications were made to the default project, enable anonymous auth (per codelab), and add firestore in production mode.

... I've googled for this **"firestore.rules:0:0 - ERROR Rules content empty. Compilation aborted."** error, but nothing comes up.  Anybody else see this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried dropping `rules_version = '2';` from the beginning? My theory is it's a bug that the emulator doesn't recognize that instruction.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that this is a bug in the emulator. While testing rules changes (or unit test changes) over and over again, I sometimes get this error. If I do, all future rules changes appear to be ignored. Very strange.

Sadly, my current workaround is to stop and restart the emulators. Things will then start to work as expected.

If someone has a different solution, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests to me that your code is trying to load a file that's empty.  Check that you your configuration pointing to the correct file, and be sure to **save** the file in your text editor to make sure it contains the content you expect.

Comment: Is it possible that this could be a line-ending crlf issue?...  I think when I ran it on the Ubuntu VM and got the same error I was running code I committed from WSL.  I guess I could try from a clean checkout of the codelab.

Comment: OK... interesting/spooky:  Editing firestore.rules with vim doesn't create the error, but editing with VS Code does.   Is it possible that one is editing in place, and one is doing some kind of delete/replace whereby the file is empty in an intermediate stage?

Comment: Problem goes away in WSL / VSCode if you install the suggested WSL VSCode plugin.